# How to convert JSON to simple 2D Array ?

Tags: java, json, java-8

I have a JSONObject that looks like this

```
[{"key1":1,"key2":"yyy","key3":"4"..........}, 
{"key1":2,"key2":"xxx","key3":"5"...........}, 
{"key1":3,"key2":"zzz","key3":"6"...........}]
```

I need to convert it into a simple 2D array and remove all the keys. Keep values only

```
[{1,"yyy","4",..........}, 
{2,"xxx","5",...........}, 
{3,"zzz","6",...........}]
```

I tried iteration and loop bu this seems to be too much hassle. Is there any `drop_keys` function that will do it ?

Comment: create an object with those keys as an attribute and map the JSON using some JSON object mapper...that should be a much cleaner way to do such things.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626813/looping-and-converting-json-object-to-array?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import org.json.JSONArray;

    public class JsonToArray {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          String [] myArray = [{"key1":1,"key2":"yyy","key3":"4"},{"key1":2,"key2":"xxx","key3":"5"},{"key1":3,"key2":"zzz","key3":"6"}];
          JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
          for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
             jsArray.put(myArray[i]);
         }
         System.out.println(jsArray);
         String[] array = new String[myArray.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (String)jsArray.get(i);
         }
         System.out.println("Contents of the array :: "+Arrays.toString(array));
       }
    }
```

Comment: `String [] myArray =` is not valid. Was that supposed to be a JSON OBject or Java Array. Thank you

Comment: answer is incorrect . `String [] myArray` does not compile. Thank you